# JWT with user password in key

Tags: security, jwt, signing

I want to use JWT in my application.
Now I'm wondering if it is secure to use the users password in combination with a private secret as a key to sign my tokens. This way, tokens get invalidated if a user changes his/her password.
But maybe it makes my private secret vulnerable?
Thanks for your thoughts on that!

Comment: i guess it makes it a bit difficult to validate since I would have to load the user before hand. But that should be doable.

Answer (score 2):

The usual thing is to sign all the tokens with the same key. Simplifies the management and avoids querying the database in each request.

Signing with a key+user password is feasible and has the advantage of allowing to revoke tokens (with the  commented drawbacks).

Ensure that your signing key is enough secure deriving it from user's password and has the recommended length of the selected signature algorithm. Do not store or use user's password directly.

Comment: thanks for your answer. assuming I get valid requests most of the time, I will end up querying the database for the user anyways. so I guess it's actually not that much of a drawback?

Comment: The impact depends on your architecture. If you implement heavy services with tens of queries, an additional does not matter. But if you use microservices then it could impact in the response time.  Note also that changing the password probably is not a common request but you are penalizing all services to support this operation.

Answer (score 2):

The secret is a preshared string exchanged between the client and the server. 
So in your case:

```
         SecretString= PresharedSecret + ClientPassword
```

So, everytime the client passes a JWT token, you would need to retrieve the password from the database or have some way of preloading it and a check in case of password changes for validating the token.

This might lead to the following scenarios:

1. Everytime the client forgets his password, you might need to make database calls that can be expensive
2. It would enhance security in one way, as anyone who changes the password will not be able to communicate with the server with knowledge of the previous SecretString.
   A new preshared secret will need to be decided.. and validated with the new registered password.

Overall, it does increase security. However, it depends on the purpose or the usage of the infrastructure. If it is a system in which users frequently forget passwords.. this might not be a great option.